# Issues uploading images

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have successfully been able to store user entered information into parse, but I have been having difficulty storing images into to parse, to be able to retrieve at a later date.

To clarify this, below is the code I have used for my profile creation activity, an activity that is prompted after the user has signing using social media and responds to a series of questions like age, preferred name, and where those information are later updated in the parse database and added to the current user.

Also in the activity, the user is already able to upload a picture from their device, my issue now resolves around taking that uploaded picture and storing it on parse, and associating the image with the current user who has signing using their social media account - the social media integration is done through parse.

I have looked into the following guide, but is still greatly confused.https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#files

Now I have tried to accomplish this, and have left my comments in the code below.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected ImageView mprofilePicture;

    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

        RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

        v.requestFocus();

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
        mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);

        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();



                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                     /* This is the section where the images is converted, saved, and uploaded. I have not been able Locate the image from the ImageView, where the user uploads the picture to imageview from either their gallery and later on from facebook */ 
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            /*fron image view */);
                    // Convert it to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

                    // Create the ParseFile
                    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profilePicture.png", image);
                    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                    file.saveInBackground();

                    // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                    currentUser.put("ImageName", "AndroidBegin Logo");

                    // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                    currentUser.put("ProfilePicture", file);

                    // Create the class and the columns
                    currentUser.saveInBackground();

                    currentUser.put("name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });



        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        Button mcancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        mcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProfileCreation.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });




        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    } 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the file to finish saving before you add it to the user.

Try adding a completion block to your `file.saveInBackground()` call, and moving all the `currentUser` manipulation into that completion block.

Comment: This is the area where I am experiencing issues. I have looked into the following tutorial - http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-image-upload-tutorial/, but it doesn't take into considering user uploading pictures and just assume its saved in drawable folder. I have also looked into a few example by parse, but is having difficulting working this out.